# mono make install fails with "Error 1"

Tags: mono, makefile

I've finally managed to get mono to build from sources, but make install invoked from the top build directory fails at the following point:

```
make[6]: Entering directory `/bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/mcs/class/System'
make install-local
WARNING: generic atexit() called from legacy shared library
make[7]: Entering directory `/bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/mcs/class/System'
MONO_PATH="./../../class/lib/build:$MONO_PATH" /bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/runtime/mono-wrapper ./../../class/lib/build/gacutil.exe /i ./../../class/lib/net_4_5/System.dll /f /root /usr/mono/lib /package 4.5
make[7]: *** [install-local] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory `/bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/mcs/class/System'
make[6]: *** [do-install] Error 2
```

Error 1 is the only error thrown.

I can run this command without errors

```
MONO_PATH="./../../class/lib/build:$MONO_PATH" /bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/runtime/mono-wrapper ./../../class/lib/build/gacutil.exe /i ./../../class/lib/net_4_5/System.dll /f /root /usr/mono/lib /package 4.5
```

And I can run the final command in mono-wrapper without errors

```
/bld/mono/mono-4.0.0 $ /bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/libtool --verbose --mode=execute "mono/mini/mono" --config "/bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/runtime/etc/mono/config" "mcs/class/lib/build/gacutil.exe" /i mcs/class/lib/net_4_5/System.dll /f /root /usr/mono/lib /package 4.5
```

But running 'make install' fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on where you are installing to you might need `sudo`.

Comment: sudo isn't available in the environment I'm using (android) but I managed to find the issue....the problem was with how rules.make constructed paths.

Comment: You might want to provide an answer yourself so future visitors can benefit.

Comment: I will as soon as I can pull it together...and figure out if answering my own questions is a no no.  Last question I asked...then answered...got down-voted

Comment: If no one bothers to comment on why they downvoted you then I wouldn't worry about it, as long as your answer really does answer your question then you're doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
make --debug=V install
```

revealed that it was failing when attempting to execute line 197 of mcs/build/library.make, which is:

```
196 install-local: $(gacutil)
197         $(GACUTIL) /i $(the_lib)  /f $(gacdir_flag) /root $(GACROOT) $(package_flag)
```

Removing the $(package_flag) variable allowed the build to complete successfully. **Caveat**: I'm not sure if doing so breaks the install in other ways.  Just in case...for future reference...here's the relevant entry in 'man gacutil':

```
COMMANDS
       -i  <assembly_path>  [-check_refs]  [-package  NAME]  [-root   ROOTDIR]
       [-gacdir GACDIR]

        Installs  an  assembly into the global assembly cache. <assembly_path>
       is the name of the file that contains the assembly manifest

       The -package option can be used to also create a directory in  in  pre-
       fix/lib/mono  with  the  name  NAME,  and  a  symlink  is  created from
       NAME/assembly_name to the assembly on the GAC.  This is used so  devel-
       opers can reference a set of libraries at once.

       The  -root option is used to specify the "libdir" value of an installa-
       tion prefix which differs from the prefix of the system  GAC.   Typical
       automake  usage  is  "-root $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/lib".  To access assem-
       blies installed to a prefix other than the mono prefix, it is necessary
       to set the MONO_GAC_PREFIX environment variable.

       The  -gacdir  option  is included for backward compatibility but is not
       recommended for new code. Use the -root option instead.
```

Basically, -package appears to be optional.

Feel free to edit this with corrections if necessary.